# Cookies in ruby on rails - Login in different browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I am new to web development.
I am using rails 4.2.
If a user logs in from a browser (chrome for instance), its session is stored in cookie (with a remember_token variable). 
If the same user logs in from a different browser (firefox), its remember_digest (a hash of remember_token variable using Bcrypt) in DB is overwritten and hence is invalid for the other browser.

How can I solve this problem?
Is it possible to keep the same remember_token and remember_digest for different browsers?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using any particular gem for authentication?

Comment: No I am not using a gem..
I followed Michael Hartl's tutorial for authentication

Comment: Different browsers have different cookies--they're different applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of problematic. Here's why:

1. Cookies are browser dependent, as you're already aware.
2. Being able to recreate digests(by creating methods that do what you want) is insecure. It defeats the whole purpose of using remember digests.

I can't say I recommend the following but:

One simple way of doing it is having multiple remember digests in database. Imagine having remember_digest0 and remember_digest1. In this case, you could support 2 browsers at a time(before overriding). You can add as many as you want.

-You'll need to update your authentication methods to check each digest saved in database and do stuff if any match.
-You'll need to tweak the methods for saving digests. You'll need to check which one is null or oldest, then save your new digest into that null/oldest.

Due to the nature of cookies and their security implications, this is probably the only safe way to do it. Even then I don't think it's worth it.